# Get anchor component by react ref, and update it's href field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, create-ref

I have a react code, where I have " < a > " component. When I click on "< a >", I want to change it's href field. For that, I have "ref" to get the component inside the "onclick" method like this:

```
class SomeComponent {
    public ref: React.RefObject<any>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        <a
          href="#"
          ref={ this.ref }
          onClick={this.clicked()}
        />
    } 

    private clicked() {
        const link = this.ref.current;
        link.href = "some_link"; // This doesn't have any effect on the "a" element
    }
}
```

But as a result "href" doesn't get updated. It stays to be "#" after the click as well. Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: i believe you should change `onClick={this.clicked()}` to `onClick={this.clicked}`. Because you are calling the click and not passing its reference.

Comment: Are you also looking to redirect to the link post a click?

Comment: I just want the href to be updated. clicked is getting called and link is extracted as well. But the href is not updated as a result.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of typos or bugs in the code that you've posted:

- Missing `extends React.Component`.
- Missing `return` in `render()`.
- Calling `this.clicked()` instead of passing a function to `onClick`.
- Not checking that `link` isn't `null` before assigning to it.
- Not calling `e.preventDefault()` on the click event to prevent rerendering to "#".

You could fix all of those errors and it would *mostly* work, but if the component re-renders for any reason then the the `href` will go back to `"#"` because that is what's set in the `render()`.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  public ref: React.RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>;

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <a href="#" ref={this.ref} onClick={this.clicked}>
        Anchor Text
      </a>
    );
  }

  private clicked = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    const link = this.ref.current;
    if (link && link.href === "#" ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      link.href = "some_link";
    }
  };
}
```

#### Just Use State

It doesn't make any sense to modify the `href` through DOM manipulation when **you** are the one who is setting the `href` in the first place.  Store the current value of the `href` in `this.state` and render your link with `href={this.state.href}`.

We still need to conditionally call `e.preventDefault()` only when `href` is `"#"` so this is still a weird design that can be improved.  Maybe show a `div` until its clicked an an `a` after?  But per your requirements, this will work:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<{}, { href: string }> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      href: "#"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <a href={this.state.href} onClick={this.clicked}>
        Anchor Text
      </a>
    );
  }

  private clicked = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if ( this.state.href === "#" ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ href: "some_link" });
    }
  };
}
```